# MySql Left Join not preserving Left Table

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

So I have a simple data structure:

**blog_entries**

```
 id | category | title | body | desc| date
```

**blog_comments**

```
 id | entry_id | author | email | website | body | date
```

I am trying to LEFT JOIN blog_comments ON entry_id to get teh COUNT on comments for each entry. I only have two records in 'blog_entries' and none in 'blog_comments' ATM. For some reason when I run the query below, I only get one result back:

```
SELECT
    blog_entries.*,
    COUNT(blog_comments.id) AS comment_count        
    FROM blog_entries
        LEFT JOIN blog_comments 
            ON blog_entries.id = blog_comments.entry_id
```

I do not understand why my LEFT table is not being preserved.

Comment: check your data carefully, there must be some issues with your data

Comment: This query wouldn't really achieve what you want to achieve (need a GROUP BY), but you should be getting more than one result if the data is how you describe. Something is amiss here it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your left table is not being preserved, because according to: [Group by functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html)

If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

You should use:

```
SELECT
    blog_entries.*, 
    COALESCE( c.cnt, 0 ) as comment_count
FROM blog_entries
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT entry_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM blog_comments
    GROUP BY entry_id ) c
ON blog_entries.id = c.entry_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the "GROUP BY" as commented by smp7d, I would change it to count(*).  if the left join is NULL to the comments, is that throwing you the problem?

```
select 
      be.*,
      count(*)
   from
      blog_entries be
         left join blog_comments bc
           on be.id = bc.entry_id
   group by
     be.id
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` will count 1 for blog_entries without comments.